# Grabbing Parts of Variable To Echo Within HTML

Tags: php, mysql, variables

How how would I just grab the first few words of a variable such as $data for example. I'm trying to create an article preview section and that variable is an article. I'm trying to display of course only a preview of it.

```
    <?php
$sql = "SELECT author, data, postdate, Title, previewimg FROM articlepreview ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql);
$prev = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $a = $row["author"];
    $data = $row["data"];
    $postdate = $row["postdate"];
    $title = $row["Title"];
    $previewimg = $row["previewimg"];
    $prev .= '
<div class="wrapPreviewArticle">


    <div style="headerPreview"><h4>'.$title.'</h4></div>
    <div class="wrapPreviewRow">
    <div style="imagePreview"><img src="'.$previewimg.'" height="20%" width="20%" alt="'.$title.'" /></div>
    <div clas="wordPreview">'.$data.'</div>
    </div>
</div>
';
}
?>
```

Once I've got this I would spit out the variable

```
<body>
<div><?php echo $prev; ?></div> <!--with only the desired portion.-->
</body>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: SQL: `SELECT author, data, postdate, SUBSTRING(data,0,100) ...`  
PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use SUBSTRING_INDEX on your query:

```
"SELECT author, SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, ' ', 5) data, ... FROM articlepreview ..."
```

This will extract only the first 5 words from the field `data`.

Comment: I got it from here...thanks everyone for the quick responses...Fantastic! I had no idea how to do this though it should be so basic.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab for example the first 200 characters and display only this as a preview

```
$pos=strpos($data, ' ', 200);
$preview=substr($data,0,$pos );
```

This will also make sure you split it at the space not in the middle of the word

Answer (score 0):

You could show the first X characters (X here is 20):

```
    <div class="wordPreview">'.substr($data, 0, 20).'</div>
```